# The rate of change of speed when turning back along a straight line

Tags: kinematics

I was trying to find how the rate of change of spped at $t$ of an object moving in a straight line relates to its maginitude of it acceleration. The case when it is moving in the direction before and after $t$ is easy.

However, an object is moving along a staight path and turns back at time $t_t$, then its $\vec v$  is $s(t)\hat i$ when $t<t_t$, and $-s(t)\vec i$ when $t>t_t$, where $s$ is the speed function. Differentiating $\vec v$ for $t<t_t$ we have $\vec a=s'(t)\hat i$, and for $t>t_t$ we have $\vec a=-s'(t)\hat i$. Since $s'$ is continuous, the former tends to $s'(t_t)\hat i$ as $t\to t_t^-$, and the latter to $-s'(t_t)\hat i$ as $t\to t_t^+$. Since $\vec a$ is continuous, we have $s'(t_t)=0$.

I have been assuming all functions related to displacement like speed, velocity, and so on are continuous.

But then I considered the following scenario. When a ball is thrown upwards and moves only under the influence of gravity, its $s'$ is $-g$ before and $g$ after its hightest point. So $s'$ is undefined when the ball is at maximum height.

I have been assuming all kinematic functions are continous. Is this wrong?

Comment: Just real quick: you're using the same speed function for both up and down, but I think this isn't correct. I think I can write an answer, but let $t_i=0$. Then $\vec{v} = s(t)\hat{j}$ on the way up and $\vec{v} = -s(-t)\hat{j}$ on the way down.

Comment: Continuity of a function does not imply continuity of it's derivatives, therefore one wouldn't immediately assume $s''(t)$ is continuous just because $s'(t)$ is. But if you require that $s''(t)$ be continuous it forces $s'(t)$ to not only be continuous but also free of sharp points.

Comment: Maybe it could be more suited to [Math.stack](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299315/is-a-function-differentiable-if-it-has-a-removable-discontinuity). You can construct any function as you need it, however if you build it with a removable discontinuity (as it seems you are trying to do so),- then of course it's not continuous, nor differentiable. Also I do not see a point to define two versions of speed, it's just one form $\vec v = s(t) \hat i$, because unit vector $\hat i$ includes the fact of changing speed direction, it's vector after all ! Then it will be continuous.

Comment: @Triatticus I said I have been assuming all kinematic functions are continuous. I meant all functions related to speeds, velocity, displacement, and so on. I did not say because a function is continuous, its derivative is continuous.

Comment: @TFR that was a newly added assumption/edit before I made that comment, so at the time it did not seem like that was your intent. With the new information it's an outdated comment now. In the case of vertical motion the acceleration is $-g$ before and after $t_r$ as in the first case the object is slowing down while the second the object is speeding up, *in the downward direction* (increasing negative velocity). I'm not sure why you think that the sign of a changes during that situation.

Answer (score 2):

Let's choose a time coordinate system so that $t=0$ is the moment when the ball reaches it's peak.  Then, by assumption, the speed at time $t$ is the same as the speed at time $-t$, but the velocity is exactly *opposite*. Then, our velocity function is the following:
$$
\vec{v}(t) = \begin{cases}
s(t)\hat{j} & t\leq0\\
-s(-t)\hat{j} & t > 0
\end{cases}\,.
$$
Note the important $(-t)$ in the argument of $s$ for the way down!  This guarantees that the speed is identical the same amount $\Delta t$ of time before the peak as after the peak:
$$
\left|s\left(t=-\Delta t\right)\right| = \left|-s\left(-\left(t=\Delta t\right)\right)\right|\,.
$$
Once we've established that, then we can take some derivatives.  The acceleration is
$$
\frac{d\vec{v}(t)}{dt} = \begin{cases}
s'(t)\hat{j} & t\leq0\\
-(-1)s'(-t)\hat{j} & t > 0
\end{cases}
= \begin{cases}
s'(t)\hat{j} & t\leq0\\
s'(-t)\hat{j} & t > 0
\end{cases}\,.
$$
Now, the accelerations at equal times on either side of the peak are equal, because $s'(t)$ for $t<0$ is equal to $s'(-|t|)$. In the limit as $t\to0$ from either side, then, the derivatives are the same, which means the derivative exists and is unique there.

Finally, in the case of simple free-fall projectile motion, $s(t)$ on the way up is a decreasing function of time and constant, so $s'(t)=-g$. Thus, throughout the entire trip, the acceleration is $\vec{a} = -g\hat{j}$, and continuity of the acceleration is guaranteed, and hence the velocity and the position are also continuous.

---

To match the OP, where the time at the peak is $t_i$, we have to shift everything, and that makes it difficult to analyze.  But, here would be the correct velocity function:
$$
\vec{v}(t) = \begin{cases}
s(t)\hat{j} & t\leq t_i\\
-s(-t+2t_i)\hat{j} & t > 0
\end{cases}\,.
$$
Note that for times $t_i-\Delta t$ and $t_i+\Delta t$ (equal times away from the peak on either side), we get
$$
s(t<t_i) = s(t_i-\Delta t)$$
and
$$
s(t>t_i) = \left(-(t_i+\Delta t)+2t_i\right) = s(t_i-\Delta t)\,,
$$
and the speeds are the same!

---

Finally, what about the "speed function" itself, as mentioned in the OP?  Let's consider the simple case of free-fall again, and think about the graph of the speed as a function of time.  It will look like a shifted absolute-value function, since the speed decreases linearly, hits zero, the increases linearly.  The speed function is continuous at that point but not differentiable!  Hence, the derivative of the speed function is discontinuous.  So, not all kinematic quantities (if you consider the speed function and its derivative as kinematic quantities) need be continuous, even for the mathematically "very nice" case of constant-acceleration motion.

Comment: The problem is $s'(t)$ is not continuous at the peak of a ball. Before reaching the peak, it is $-g$, and when moving downwards, it is $+g$. So you cannot differentiate $s'(t)$ at $t=0$. My original question was I have been assuming all kinematic functions are continous. Is this wrong?

Comment: @TFR But your calculation is not the right calculation, because $-s(t)$ is *not* the speed function for the way down.  Taking into account the symmetry of the problem, you have to do what I did, which is to use $s(t)$ on the way up and $-s(-t+2t_i)$ on the way down. Then, the derivative of this piecewise-defined function *is* continuous (and is in fact always equal to $-g$ in the case of free-fall near the surface of the Earth).

Comment: I was not considering the scenario of the motion of a ball thrown upwards at the beginning. So that is a general formula. I think there is some misunderstanding. I used $s$ to mean the speed function of an object so that $s(t)$ is the speed of an object at $t$. I wrote in the post exactly this: """[i]ts ⃗  is ()̂  when $t<t_t$, and −()⃗  when $t>t_t$, where  is the speed function.""" I think you misread that I use t for the same thing. I meant all $t$ near and $>t_t$ (time of turning), and all $t$ near and after $t_t$

Comment: I might see what you mean.  I mean, if you were to plot the *speed* of an object for the simple case of a constant acceleration, then the function would piecewise-linear. At the turning point, where the speed goes to zero, the graph would display a *cusp*; in other words the graph would be a shifted absolute-value function. So yes, the *speed* function is not differentiable at that point, and hence its derivative is discontinuous.  However, that doesn't imply that the acceleration is discontinuous, because you should be taking derivatives of the *velocity* to get that, which is what I've done.

Comment: I think you thought my problem was ending up with an acceleration undefined. I said the rate of change of speed. But anyway, I sought to find a connection between the rate of change of speed at point of turning and its acceleration and ended up finding the former undefined in some cases. And that is why I described acceleration using speed. Actually I just found out assuming $s'$ continuous at time of turning leads to $\vec a$ always $\vec 0$. But $it$ will never be undefined. And the formula not taking symmetry into account has only one negative sign, whereas the one doing so has two.

Comment: But the question is, since $s'$ is undefined at time of turing, why did you still differentiate $s$ at $t=0$? (You did that in the piecewise definition of $\vec a$.)

Comment: Well, defining things the way I did, you can show that the derivative of $s(t)$ from the left (which is well-defined as you pointed out in your OP) is equal to the derivative of $-s(-t+2t_i)$ from the right, which implies that the piecewise-defined function that creates $\vec{v}(t)$ is differentiable at $t=t_i$. But as you pointed out, you were thinking about the speed itself, not the velocity, which was my confusion.  In any case, you're right: the only way for $s'(t)$ to be defined at a turning point is if the acceleration is zero. That way, $s$ can go to zero quadratically.

Comment: I think if one uses the speed to define velocity in such a scenario, the acceleration at $t_t$ can be found either using the orignal definition of a derivative, or using the fact that accleration is continuous and taking the side limits of $s'$ rather than computing $s'$ at $0$ which does not exist. And I am not sure whether accleration is always continuous now because I just found out one function about its maginitude is not continuous.

Comment: But you wrote $\frac{d\vec v}{dt}(t)=s'(t)\hat j\quad t\leq 0$, which implies $\frac{d\vec v}{dt}(0) = s'(0)$ = undefined.

Comment: That's implicitly a derivative from the left, and the other part ($s'(-t)$) is implicitly a derivative from the right, as I *think* is made clear by the paragraph below that. The point there is then to show that (again, under the assumption of constant-acceleration motion like projectile motion where the situation is "symmetric" about the peak) the derivative of $\vec{v}$ is then well-defined because the derivatives from either side are equal. For a more general case that's not symmetric, we'd still need to make some assumptions to make this work, like maybe the acceleration is continuous.

Comment: In this symmetric situation, the continuity of the derivative of $\vec v$ is needed in the first place in order for your method work. You did not show how symmetry implies continuity. You used continuity and symmetry to show the existence of $\vec a$. I mean if you know the continuity of $\vec a$, why do you need symmetery? You only need to consider the behavior of $\vec a$ at one side.

Comment: So you mean the onesided limits of the limit of difference quotient of $$ as $→0$? Isn't the ' symbol always used to represent the derivative of a function? Indeed it is symmetric around time of of a ball at maximum height. But how do you know that limit of the limit exists in the first place? If one exists, yes, it is equal to the other one, and the limit exists.(because of symmetry). But how do you know one exists. Even the limit of the limit does exist, how to you konw the acutual value (the limit of the difference quocient i.e. the derivative) exists?